# Autocomplete Jquery alternatives

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I need to create and autocomplete like [this](http://www.booking.com/)

I guess Jquery UI won't be able to do stuff like this?

Will I need to hand write it, or what head start would you recommend?

Comment: Why is jQuery not capable of doing this? Its a framework, at its core its javascript. It can all be done.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Jakub I said "I guess", and put a question mark at the end. I haven't tried anything yet, I'm here for advice before wasting time. Have a nice day.

Comment: @iKode no intent of being rude, however, researching on your own and learning is not "wasting time" - it's what you should be doing before you ask a question here. :]

Comment: @user1090190 I am researching. I'm asking my peers their advice, where to start, as in evidence by the great links / code below. For info I'm not working on this particular piece of code. I was already told by the deleloper who is that is isn't possible with JQuery, which is why I asked, and why I was looking for alternatives. I'm up to my eyes on something else and he was continuing to write an autocomplete from scratch which seemed wrong to me. Hang me, shoot me, whatever... then go look in the mirror...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean the customised output of the autocomplete suggestions? You can customise the output of the autocomplete results with jQuery - no problem. For example:

```
$(this).autocomplete().data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                    return $("<li></li>")
                        .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                        .append($("<a></a>").html(item.label))
                        .append($("<span>whatever you fancy in here..</span>"))
                        .appendTo(ul);
                };
```

I suggest you Google "monkey patching jquery autocomplete" for more details.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is leading and the most powerful JavaScript library: it has many plugins for a specific functianality like Autocomplete. however alternatives are Dojo Toolkit, Prototype, Mootools and...

check this:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Answer (score 1):

Try this http://code.google.com/p/jquery-autocomplete/

Answer (score 1):

This can be done easily with jQuery autocomplete. Check out this plug-in for autocomplete: 
https://github.com/scottgonzalez/jquery-ui-extensions/blob/master/autocomplete/jquery.ui.autocomplete.html.js